# Machine Learning in C# for predictions

Tags: c#, machine-learning, random-forest

I have a large set of records in an excel file where I have 6 variables from which I have one price variable which is dependent on all other 5 variables. 
I want to create an application where I can **predict price** in the future on the bases of previous entered data set, where my input is that five variables and I need to predict the 6th variable, which is the price.

How can I do that in C#?

Comment: Then you should do it in F#? :)

Answer (score 1):

another library to look at is http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

Comment: Please tell me how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

try to use MATlab c# libraries for the predictions....
you can train application using the previous data and then you can get the result for the future

Answer (score 0):

Im no expert on this issue, but I think you can use a neural network to try to predict the price based on an input.

In .Net there is a VERY good library. http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

The idea is to create a network that takes 5 inputs and have only one output. Then train it with the data you have. That should give you a near perfect solution, but not an optimal one.

Of course, for this to work, there should be a relation between those inputs and the price. What this will do it figure it out for you.